# In Google Sheets, I am trying to write a formula to return a value to a sheet

Tags: google-sheets

If the value in column "A" = "X", and the value in column "B" = "Y", then return the value in column "C"

Answer (score 1):

For Row1:

```
=if(and(A1="X",B1="Y"),C1,"")
```

The inverted commas should not be required if the values are numeric (not `X` and `Y` but say `3` and `4`). The final pair are to leave the cell blank where the condition is not met.

[IF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)
[AND](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093301)

Depending upon locale, the `,`s might need to be `;`s.